# XeLaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/pcr/m/n' undefined (Font)

Tags: fonts, xetex, warnings, typewriter

The commands \textbf and \texttt don't have an effect.

XeLaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/pcr/m/n' undefined

.cls file:

```
\RequirePackage{fmtcount}

\newcommand{\setthesistype}[1]{\def\@thesistype{#1}}
\let\thesistype\setthesistype
\newcommand{\show@thesistype}{\@thesistype}

%\newcommand{\uselogo}{\def\@uselogo{yes}}

\global\let\@examiner\@empty
\newcommand{\setexaminer}[1]{\def\@examiner{#1}}
\let\examiner\setexaminer

\global\let\@supervisor\@empty
\newcommand{\setsupervisor}[1]{\def\@supervisor{#1}}
\let\supervisor\setsupervisor

\newcommand{\birthinfo}[1]{\normalsize \GetTranslation{born} #1}
\newcommand{\matricnumber}[1]{\normalsize \GetTranslation{matriculationnumber}: #1}

\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \ifx\@uselogo\@empty
            \null\vskip16mm
        \else
            \begin{flushright}
                \includegraphics[height=16mm]{gfx/ubn-logo}
                \includegraphics[height=35mm]{gfx/hrl-logo}\par
            \end{flushright}
        \fi
        \null\vfil\vskip60pt
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.618034\paperwidth}
            \centering
            {\Large \textsc{\show@thesistype}\par}\vspace{1ex}
            \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\\
            {\Huge\bfseries\@title\par}
            \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\vspace{2cm}
        \end{minipage}\par

        {\emph{\GetTranslation{written-submitted}}\\\vspace{1em}
        \Large
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            \@author
        \end{tabular}\par}\vspace{2cm}

        {\def\and{\end{tabular}\\ \personprefix & \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}\begin{tabular}[t]{l} }
        \def\arraystretch{1.5}
        \newcounter{examinercnt}
        \setcounter{examinercnt}{0}
        \gdef\personprefix{\stepcounter{examinercnt}\ordinal{examinercnt} \GetTranslation{examiner}:}
        \Large
        \global\let\@needtable\@empty
        \ifx\@examiner\@empty\else
            \gdef\@needtable{yes}
        \fi
        \ifx\@supervisor\@empty\else
            \gdef\@needtable{yes}
        \fi
        \ifx\@needtable\@empty\else%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
                \ifx\@examiner\@empty\else\personprefix & \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\@examiner\end{tabular}\fi\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\\
                \ifx\@supervisor\@empty\else
                    \gdef\personprefix{}
    %               \makeatletter
    %               \global\def\personprefix\@empty
    %               \makeatother
                    \GetTranslation{supervisors}: & \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\@supervisor\end{tabular}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
                \fi
            \end{tabular}%
        \fi}
        \vfill\null
        {\@date\par}
    \end{titlepage}
}

\RequirePackage{iftex}

\RequirePackage[margin=3cm,bindingoffset=3mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr,emptypage,xcolor,graphicx,subcaption,booktabs}
\RequirePackage[labelfont=bf,format=hang]{caption}

\definecolor{ub-blue}{cmyk}{1,0.7,0,0}
\definecolor{ub-yellow}{cmyk}{0,0.3,1,0}
\definecolor{ub-gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0.15,0.55}

\RequirePackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,
            filecolor=black,
            urlcolor=ub-blue,
            citecolor=ub-blue, %black, %darkblue,
            bookmarksnumbered=true
            }


\fancypagestyle{mlai-fancy}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\sffamily\small\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\small\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\small\rightmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\sffamily\small\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{13pt}

\pagestyle{mlai-fancy}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\RequirePackage[intlimits]{mathtools}

\RequirePackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newenvironment{abstract}{
\small%
\begin{center}
    \bfseries\GetTranslation{abstractname}
\end{center}%
\quotation%
}{\endquotation}

\ifPDFTeX
    \wlog{PDF LaTeX detected}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{textcomp,tgpagella}
\else
    \ifLuaTeX
        \wlog{LuaLaTeX detected}
        \RequirePackage{fontspec}
        \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
    \else
        \ifXeTeX
            \wlog{XeLaTeX detected}
            \RequirePackage{fontspec}
            \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
```

Answer (score 1):

What you posted does not per itself allow to reproduce the problem.  Probably the preamble or some other package is also doing `\usepackage{courier}` or `\usepackage{times}` which are packages for interacting with font encodings such as OT1, T1, ... suitable for pdfLaTeX, not the TU which becomes default font encoding with XeLaTeX and is used to fit "Unicode" font into the LaTeX font system.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
    \wlog{PDF LaTeX detected}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{textcomp,tgpagella}
\else
    \ifLuaTeX
        \wlog{LuaLaTeX detected}
        \RequirePackage{fontspec}
        \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
    \else
        \ifXeTeX
            \wlog{XeLaTeX detected}
            \RequirePackage{fontspec}
            \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
        \fi
    \fi
\fi

% \usepackage{times}
% or
\usepackage{courier}
\begin{document}
\texttt{foo}
\showoutput\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
% Local variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

and there is warning:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TU+pcr on input line 27
.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file TUpcr.fd. on input line 27.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/pcr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 27.
```

The `\showoutput` triggered extra information in the log

```
...\hbox(7.05+0.10999)x345.0, glue set 314.16fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 foo
....\kern 0.0
```

confirming this.

So you should identify what in your set-up leads to using such font packages which are specific to PDFLaTeX.  What your posted (at time of writing this) does *not*.

---

In investigating this I hit against a strange thing with LaTeX NFSS.  In the above I used `\usepackage{times}` rather than `\usepackage{courier}` and expected the exact same.  Although warning is indeed the same

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TU+pcr on input line 27
.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file TUpcr.fd. on input line 27.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/pcr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 27.
```

the `\showoutput` box log diplays:

```
...\hbox(7.05+0.10999)x345.0, glue set 313.33fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\TU/ptm/m/n/10 foo
....\kern 0.0
....\glue 3.33 plus 1.665 minus 1.11
```

notice the unexpected `\TU/ptm...` therein.

The PDF does contain the announced Latin Modern font.  But the showoutput log uses a fontname macro which somewhere else the system must know is not available.  On has to find higher up int the log that `TU/lmr` was substituted to `TU/ptm`, but still `TU/ptm` is used here.

Comment: ping @FrankMittelbach regarding the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, my warning and the errors with ``\texttt``and ``textbf`` disappeared when I removed the "times" package.